# Would someone please explain this argument? (Legendre formula)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is an argument in my book.

> Theorem
>
> If $n$ is a positive integer and $p$ is a prime, then the exponent of the highest power of p that divides $n!$ is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty [\frac{n}{p^k}]$
>
> Proof>
>
> Among the first $n$ positive integers, those divisible by $p$ are $p,2p,...,[n/p]p$.
>
> Thus, (Q1) there are exactly $[n/p]$ multiples of $p$ occurring in the product that defines $n!$, namely, $p,2p,...,[n/p]p$.
>
> The exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n!$ is obtained by adding to the number of integers in $\{p,2p,...,[n/p]p\}$, the number of integers among $1,2,\cdots,n$ divisible by $p^2$, and so on. Reasoning as in the first paragraph, the integers between 1 and n that are divisible by $p^2$ are $p^2,\cdots,[n/{p^2}]p^2$.
>
> After a finite number of repetitions of this process, we are led to conclude that the total number of times $p$ divides $n!$ is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty [\frac{n}{p^k}]$

I completely don't get this argument from $(Q1)$.

Why there are exactly $[n/p]$ multiples of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n!$??

Moreover, I don't get what the author is doing after $(Q1)$.

Could someone please explain this argument in detail?

Or please suggest me a link to see a proof for this theorem.

I have googled it, but I couldn't find a proof for it.

EDIT:

I hate explaining things verbally. Please give me a formal argument..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this is obvious. If you want formally, take it. $\square$

1. How many numbers that less than $n$ and divisible by $p$? Let's count, they are $A_1 = \{p, 2p, 3p, \dots, [\frac{n}{p}]p\}$ (because $([\frac{n}{p}] + 1)p > n$). $|A_1| = [\frac{n}{p}]$.
2. Okey, then at least $p^{[\frac{n}{p}]}$ divides $n!$
3. But we absolutely didn't take into account that there are some number in $A_1$ that divisible by $p^2$, such as $A_2 = \{p^2, 2p^2, 3p^2, \dots, [\frac{n}{p^2}]p^2\}$.
4. The good thing is that $A_2 \subset A_1$ and we counted $p$ that are sitting in $A_2$ once, so we should count them only 1 more time. $|A_2| = [\frac{n}{p^2}]$.
5. Thus we conclude that at least $p^{[\frac{n}{p}] + [\frac{n}{p^2}]}$ divides $n!$
6. The same can be applied to $A_3, A_4, \dots$ That's why $n!$ is divisible by $p^{\sum_{k = 1}^\infty[\frac{n}{p^k}]}$.
7. It is easy to see that $n!$ is not divisible by $p^{1+\sum_{k = 1}^\infty[\frac{n}{p^k}]}$. $\blacksquare$